# Addressing awaiting/async steps with Protractor for Ionic

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, authentication, protractor

I am getting crazy trying to have a Protractor test suite for my Ionic 1 app.

So far I have managed to setup a working environment with basic tests, following the default tutorial, read the Protractor doc. I have also played with Elementor.

But I can't manage to handle the login use case of my app (step 1 for all other tests...), which needs an answer from a server, which takes some time. I have tried various approaches with ExpectedConditions, sleeps (even though Protractor says it does not need to this), nothing works in a deterministic way. The same tests sometimes work and sometimes don't.

So my question is: is there some tutorials or 3rd party doc that you would recommend to help me to develop reliable and deterministic Protractor tests especially to handle asynchronous stuff?

Many thanks (and merry Christmas)!

Comment: can you provide the test spec

Comment: Shame on me, your query Danny brought me to triple-check my code before plublishing it, and find a stupid bug in it... Things are going much smoother now. Thanks!